# How to transfer session main domain to sub-domain in php

Tags: php, session, cross-domain

I want to use my main domain session in subdomain for example

main domain : example.com
subdomain : xyz.example.com

session : `$_SESSION['username']`

user login in main domain and generate `$_SESSION['username']`

now i want to auto login in subdomain and work same session variable in my subdomain.

Comment: @fred how can i use ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );

Comment: just like that it's a global PHP function!? Or set the `session.cookie_domain` value in your php.ini file on the server directly.

Comment: @xander thank you for reply ... i already write it in php.ini like this session.cookie_domain = '.example.com' and write before session like ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );